# 'Page' is a type and cannot be used as an expression

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting the titled error when using the following code to close the browser window.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), "close", "window.close();", True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are passing `Page` as your first argument and I suppose it is not a variable. If you are running that from a Page object, try this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, GetType(Page), "close", "window.close();", True)
```

If you are running that from a User Control object, try this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, GetType(Page), "close", "window.close();", True)
```